# ClassCastException when loading from Redis Cache

Tags: java, jpa, caching, redis, spring-data-jpa

I geta ClassCastException when reading a response from Redis Cache. Everything looks good when hitting the DB and store it in Redis Cache. The second read out of the Redis Cache terminates in a ClassCastException when i want to iterate over the linked HashSet. When I debug the Hashmap all values are correct, until I reach the foreach loop. When I want to evaluate an Entry I get the Exception.
Is it a configuration property that i missed in the Cacheconfig?

Code:

Jpa Repository

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Usr.fullCascade")
@Cacheable(value = "UsrEntity", cacheManager = "userEntity")
Set<UsrEntity> findByCompanyidAndStatusNot(int cid, UserRoleStatus status);
```

Service

```
Set<UsrEntity> usrEntity = userRepository.findByCompanyidAndStatusNot(companyID,
UserRoleStatus.X);
usrEntity.forEach(user -> {
        userDtos.add(companyUserDataMapper.toDto(user));
});
```

CacheConfig

```
@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new 
         RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}

@Bean("userEntity")
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {

    RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = 
        RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
        .entryTtl( Duration.ofHours(1));
    redisCacheConfiguration.disableCachingNullValues();
    return RedisCacheManager
        .builder( 
         redisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(redisConnectionFactory))
        .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a proper solution so far. Its all about Thread context :)

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()

this line is necessary

```
RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration
    .defaultCacheConfig(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
    .entryTtl( Duration.ofHours(1));
```